# Set focus on an embedded player (cross domain) to access its hotkeys

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I´m implementing an embed video like this:

```
<iframe id="iframe1"  src="urltoembedplayer"></iframe>
```

I cannot access the hotkeys of the the player because the player doesn´ seem to be focused (?). How can I focus the player so the user can let´s say stop the video by hitting spacebar? The player belongs to a site which allows embedding but I doesn´t have any further permissions. No API access or whatever. I also have no permission to access "contentDocument". I tried some things but none of them work (seen below). I also run the code after a timeout to make sure the iframe is already loaded. No effect. Any ideas?

```
var iframe_window = window.frames["iframe1"];
iframe_window.contentDocument.body.focus();

$("#iframe1").click();

$("#iframe1").contents().find("#mhp1138_skin_default").click();
$("#iframe1").contents().find(".player_flv_wrapper").click();
$("#iframe1").contents().find("#flvplayer").click();

var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
var a = document.getElementById("iframe1"); 
a.dispatchEvent(evt);  


var iframe = $("#iframe1")[0];
iframe.contentWindow.focus();

document.getElementById("iframe1").contentWindow.focus()
```